# Create a conan package from a reference folders as source

Tags: python, conan, conan-2

I am trying to create a conan package from a third party library(boost). I am not trying to build the entire boost here, rather just package the header files as only those are used in most of our projects. Hence I want to package the boost directly as it is.
I have the boost downloaded and extracted it into a folder. The extracted folder structure looks like this:

C:\Users\xxxxx\Downloads\source\third_party\boost_1_70_0\boost\accumulators.....(many sub folders and files)

I want to create a package with only the contents from the '**boost**' folder. I have already tried a recipe but for some reason it copies the folder from '**third_party**'.

The conan recipe(conanfile.py) is at the same level as that of '**third_party**'.

I am new to conan so there might be something that I am missing.

Below is the recipe.

```
from conan import ConanFile
from conan.tools.files import copy
import os


class BoostRecipe(ConanFile):
    name = "boost"
    version = "1.70.0"

    # Optional metadata
    license = "xxx"
    author = "xxx"
    url = "xxx"
    description = "C++ interface to the boost library."

    # Binary configuration
    settings = "os", "compiler", "build_type", "arch"
    options = {"shared": [True, False], "fPIC": [True, False]}
    default_options = {"shared": False, "fPIC": True}

    # Sources are located in the same place as this recipe, copy them to the recipe
    exports_sources = "contents/boost_1_70_0/*"
    
    def layout(self):
        self.folders.source = "contents/boost_1_70_0"

    def package(self): 
        copy(self, pattern="*", dst="boost", src=self.folders.source, keep_path=False)

    def package_info(self):
        self.cpp_info.libs = ["Boost"]
```

Comment: Quick question: Building boost is complicated, why are you creating a recipe from scratch, and not reusing/forking/starting from the recipe already existing in ConanCenter? https://github.com/conan-io/conan-center-index/tree/master/recipes/boost

Comment: If it is a general question about how ``layout()`` works, and how to reference folders in recipes, maybe the best would be to file a ticket in https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues

Comment: @drodri I am not actually trying to build the entire boost. Our projects only use the headers, hence I want to package them and any project can download and readily use them. I will make the edits in my question.

Comment: The ``boost`` recipe in ConanCenter already has a ``header_only`` option, that if set to True, it will not build anything at all, and just package and use the headers.